# My Service doesn't start automatically when device is rebooted

Tags: android, xamarin, service, cross-platform, reboot

I want to start a service automatically when the device is restarted. After that, I want the operations in the service to be executed. I wrote a code, but it fails when the device is rebooted. I have 2 classes. These are '`AdroidService`' and '`DetectBootUp`'. I think there is an error in 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

DetectBootUp.cs

```
namespace NotifyExp2.Droid.ReminderService
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    class DetectBootUp : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Intent bootUp = new Intent(context.ApplicationContext, typeof(AndroidService));
            bootUp.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ExcludeStoppedPackages);
            bootUp.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.IncludeStoppedPackages);
            context.StartService(bootUp);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidService.cs

```
namespace NotifyExp2.Droid.ReminderService
{
    [Service]
    public class AndroidService : Service
    {
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service Created", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Log.Debug("BroadCastReceiverBoot", "OnCreate");
        }
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service Destroyed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Log.Debug("BroadCastReceiverBoot", "onDestroy");
            ApplicationContext.StartService(new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(AndroidService)));
        }
        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service Started - " + DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Log.Debug("BroadCastReceiverBoot", "OnStart");
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:label="NotificationExample"
               android:enabled="true">
    <receiver
      android:name=".DetectBootUp"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".AndroidService"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:exported="false">
    </service>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you launched the app at least once before rebooting?

Comment: Yes. I launched. 
But already I'll use it to generate notifications. The user can switch the device on and off at least once before launching the application.

Comment: You should add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> at the top of your Manifest file, not inside the <receiver tag. Remove it from there.

Comment: I did it, but it did not improve. I know how to use Google. I did not find an answer there, so I ordered it here. @AmedeoBaragiola

Comment: Your category in the Intent Filter is wrong too. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: How should I edit the Manifest file?

Comment: Are you manually editing the manifest?

Comment: yes i am manually editing this.